# Can I print what string format was matched from a multiple-string, Regex search

Tags: python, regex

In the code below, I'm searching for string, hex, and ascii .... If the string is matched, the file where the string was matched is printed. Is there a way to print what string type was matched (hex, ascii, or string)? Additionally, I would like to consider upper and lower case, and numbers [0-9]+. I'm not sure if I can add this to the same regular expression, or would it be better to add another regexp line:

```
elif searchType =='2':
      print "  Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
      directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Python27")
      userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
      userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
      userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
      regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) )
      for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
         for file in files:
             if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
                for line in f.readlines():
                   #if userstring in line:
                   if regex.search(line):       
                      print "file: " + os.path.join(root,file)           
                      break
                else:
                   print "String NOT Found!"
                   break
                f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = regex.search(line)
print result.group()
```

The regex.search will return an result object. What is returned by result.group() is the list of the matching strings, and in your case, it will a list with 1 item, the matching string HEX, ASCII or string.

Comment: Julien - when you say a call to group(), what do you mean? I'm still stumped on this

Comment: `result = regex.search(line)`
`print result.group()`

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
for line in f.readlines():
    if userstring in line:
        print 'User input in file: ' + os.path.join(root, file)
        break
    elif userStrHEX in line:
        print 'HEX string in file: ' + os.path.join(root, file)
        break
    elif userStrASCII in line:
        print 'ASCII string in file: ' + os.path.join(root, file)
        break
```

Looking at your regexp (one of three possible words and no real regexp features), I would avoid using regexp at all.

You can easily add further features:

```
    elif userstring.lower() in line.lower():
        print 'User input (case-insensitive) in file: ' + os.path.join(root, file)
        break
```

Just check the order of your conditions to catch the right case (i.e. if you check case-insensitive before case-sensitive, the latter will never happen, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! But for the sake of knowing, how would I add a case-insensitive feature to the regexp above (eg. re.IGNORECASE)?